# How to add class based on value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I'm trying to add a class based on today's date value which matches the data in JSON.

This is an example of date format output in JSON:

```
tanggal: "Sunday, 20/08/2023"
```

and here is my JS:

```
function fetchJadwal() {
  const showli = document.getElementById('showData');
  const d = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
  const date = new Date();
  
  let day = date.getDate();
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  let valuedate = d[date.getDay() - 1] + ', ' + day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
  
  let col = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < jadwal.length; i++) {
    var obj = jadwal[i];
    var objTgl = jadwal[i].tanggal;
    // objTgl = Sunday, 20/08/2023
    var classActive = (attrbDate == objTgl) ? "active" : "";
    col += `<li value='${objTgl}' class='${classActive}'></li>`;
  }
  showli.innerHTML = col;
}

fetchJadwal()
```

but this is not working properly.

Even though when I changed valuedate to `valuedate = 'Sunday, 20/12/2023';`

it works, but the first code fails.

Comment: You have not defined `attrbDate`.

Answer (score 1):

`getDay()` returns days starting at 0, so if you're on Sunday, you'll be trying to access `d[-1]`, which is undefined.
You're also starting `col` as an array but adding strings, which does work in JS, but you may want to just start with a string instead.

Comment: thanks it worked for me after i also parsed the `objDate` and `valuedate` data to `date.toLocaleDateString();`. I'm a little confused, because I myself am still in the learning stage.